# How to turn off project facets on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, facet

I was trying to resolve a problem in my eclipse so I clicked on :

```
Propreties -> Project Facets -> Click on the link
```

Now I have a new view of `Project Facets` and a lot of errors and I don't know how to come back to the previous step and cancel this thing.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use the checkbox right next to each of the facets?

Comment: I did it, but I still have errors on dependencies. It doesn't reconize maven annotations.

Comment: In that case it seems like we need more information, i.e. which facet you're talking about, which problems (best with examples) you're facing etc.

Comment: I'm using maven, and when I activated Project Facets, I lost dependecies, and all maven annotations were unknown. Even after checking almost all checkboxes in Project Facets it still didn't work, so I deleted the project, imported it again, after a Maven update and a refresh every thing came back to work

Comment: @Chinovski : please consider accepting Rafael's answer. He did a good job. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Go to your `/workspace/project/`
- Edit `.project` file
- Make a **backup** of this file as a precaution

Search `<nature>` tag and remove all references, except this one:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
```

The above line says you are using a maven project.

Remove other lines like:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
```

Comment: Chinovski & @RannLifshitz thanks for your feedback. I am grateful to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to turn off Eclipse facets which gave me a few problems with the Spring related to drivers, something like "cannot establish a connection".

Right click project -> Project Natures -> search for 'Eclipse faceted Project Properties' -> Remove -> Apply and close.

This is related: also when you click Update Maven project and it regains the warning or problems which you've fixed before, then I think it is because of incompatibilities between the versions of Dynamic Web, Java and so on, with versions from maven dependency.

Comment: I cannot see Project Natures option when I right click my project?