# How To Turn Off Project Facets After Turning Them On in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I turned on Project Facets as it was recommended as a solution to another problem I was having in my workspace. As soon as I clicked on it errors everywhere, I can't uninstall and reimport the workspace there is too much involved in setting it up. What can I do to go back to the state it was in?

Also, I can't just unclick "Java" the errors are still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off project facets on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206320/how-to-turn-off-project-facets-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes encountered similar problems with other facets.

As a last resort and workaround I suggest to examine the `.project` file. Sometimes eclipse removes the facet itself but leaves `buildSpecs`. Try to remove the Java related.