# How do I stop Eclipse from complaining about a Facet error?

Tags: java, eclipse, facet

I'm getting this error "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet" when opening a Java project in Eclipse that uses a Gradle file.

I don't know what a Facet means in this context. It is not anything I ever set up intentionally.

When I search for answers to this problem, most of them start by saying to open the project properties and find the section labeled Facets, but I have no such section.

I'm running the latest version of Eclipse.

How do I completely disable "facets"? I don't even know what they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off project facets on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206320/how-to-turn-off-project-facets-on-eclipse)

Comment: Is it just a Java project?

Comment: Yes, a Java project (not J2EE). I didn't think plain Java projects could have facets, and indeed, there are no facet settings in the project properties, so I can't even adjust it.

Comment: The instructions in the other post didn't help me. Gradle simply rewrote the project file and restored the offending lines.